# How to add to Aptana helpful panel with snippets?

Tags: aptana

tell me please, how can i add top panel like on a screenshot?
(with comment blocks and helpful snippets)

[image: Screenshot.]

[Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OErcr.jpg) for full size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top toolbar on the HTML/CSS/JS editors from Aptana 2 is not in Aptana 3. You can achieve the same functionality using various commands and snippets. Look under the Commands menu for each languages for some of the new commands with their keybindings.

You can also read more on Rubles here: http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Ruble+Specification

And the rubles themselves can be seen on Github:
https://github.com/aptana/js.ruble
https://github.com/aptana/css.ruble
https://github.com/aptana/html.ruble