# HTML editor in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: aptana

Is there any choice (plugin, etc.) to get table with HTML tags like in Aptana 1.5?

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of [How to add to Aptana helpful panel with snippets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743572/how-to-add-to-aptana-helpful-panel-with-snippets/6748868#6748868)

Short answer: no, there's no way to get this toolbar in Studio 3. But there are much better options using keyboard shortcuts, snippets or commands. Please read my answer on the duplicate question.